# svg lines in D3 from csv (as separate lines not one single line) - not displaying

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am drawing some svg lines in d3.js
I've set it up this way rather than using d3.svg.line() so that **each line is separate and I can give each a distinct class**.
However, my lines aren't showing up, because they aren't getting acquiring the y2 attribute.

Screenshot from console:
[image]

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data){

          svg.selectAll("line")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("svg:line")
              .attr("x1", function(d, i) { return data[i].x })
              .attr("y1", function(d, i) { return data[i].y})
              .attr("x2", function(d, i) { return data[i+1].x})
              .attr("y2", function(d, i) { return data[i+1].y})
              .attr("fill", "none")
              .attr("stroke", "red")
              .attr("class", function(d,i){return "line" + i;});
    });

    </script>
```

[Here is a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ClxnlgnKhTQSYBlQ77zl?p=preview), which also includes the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your x2 and y2 functions will error on the final object in the array because they are trying to access the next line which doesn't exist. For example your array.length is 258 and you are on line 257; the x2 and y2 functions will try to access line 258 which doesn't exist. Try:

```
svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("svg:line")
          .attr("x1", function(d, i) { return data[i].x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d, i) { return data[i].y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d, i) {

            // this the fix
            // if there is a line at i+1 we will use it
            // otherwise use the line at index 0
            return data[i+1] ? data[i+1].x : data[ 0 ].x ;

          })
          .attr("y2", function(d, i) {

            // same as above but for y
            return data[i+1] ? data[i+1].y : data[ 0 ].y ;

          })
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke", "red")
          .attr("class", function(d,i){return "line" + i;});
```

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks so much for the explanation and solving this for me. It's really helpful.